# Implication of lack of default gateway

Tags: networking, routes

I am studying networking and operating systems and I stumbled upon this statement:

If there is no default gateway in the routing table we can't transfer packets to all the addresses.

I am asking whether the above statement is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the statement is true. Here is the definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway)

> A default gateway in computer networking is the node that is assumed
>   to know how to forward packets on to other networks. Typically, in a
>   TCP/IP network, nodes such as servers, workstations and network
>   devices each have a defined default route setting, (pointing to the
>   default gateway), defining where to send packets for IP addresses for
>   which they can determine no specific route.

A routing table can not store information of all the possible routes to which the computer may connect. So it needs a **default** mechanism to send traffic to computers for which no known path exists. The way is to route all such packets to default gateway.